# No package 'cairo' found

Tags: mono, cairo

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to compile libgdiplus (following instructions at http://www.lovesmesomecode.com/20130719-compiling-mono-3-in-ubuntu/) in preparation to install NZBdrone.

Error occurs when running ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local. (I followed all instructions prior to this.)
The instructions on this command say:

> This will configure the compilation process and ensure your computer has all the proper libaries and dependencies installed. If you ran everything above, you should be good to go. If it fails on an error and indicates you are missing a libary or package, you may need to install a development version of that package, and then try to run the command again.

The error I receive says:

> checking for CAIRO... no
>
> configure: error: Package requirements (cairo >= 1.6.4) were not met:
>
> No package 'cairo' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CAIRO_CFLAGS
>   and CAIRO_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
>   See the pkg-config man page for more details.

I found instructions at another place for installing cairo, so I tried running the command to install cairo. I also found instructions for installing libgdiplus and tried installing using 'sudo apt-get install libgdiplus.'

But each time I come back and run './autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local', I get the same error message that cairo could not be found.

Thanks for any help you might provide.

Comment: How have you installed cairo?

Comment: I have tried to install it two or three different ways. The last time I tried was using 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa'. That produced instructions in the terminal which I followed:<br>

    sudo -v

    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-team/ppa/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main ## Cairo-Dock-PPA" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E80D6BF5

    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You installed the wrong package (that one is a dock, and you are looking for one that is a graphics library). You can get the development files of Cairo using

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

In general when you are compiling some software and it asks for package `XYZ`, you can try if you have any package named `XYZ-dev` or `libXYZ-dev`

If you get further errors update your question.

Comment: PS: as I said that PPA is not needed for what you want to do. If you dont want it you can remove it using [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/310/33871).

Comment: Ok. Answer solved the problem. Also, I think I understand what you said about the 'lib' prefix and the 'dev' suffix. But how did you know to include the '2' at the end of libcairo?

Comment: In this case I already knew this was the package you needed. When you don't find an exact match you can search for packages using `apt-cache` (ex: `apt-cache search libcairo`).

Answer (score 0):

For those using Ubuntu 20.04 and above, try:

```
sudo apt install libpangocairo-1.0-0
```

Comment: Welcome! Why do you think that this package is necessary / the correct one?